# Hierarchy of generic WinForms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, generics

I have a following Form hiearchy:

```
class EditForm<T> : Form { }

class ConcreteForm : ConcreteFormDesignable { }
class ConcreteFormDesignable : EditForm<int> { }

class AdvEditForm<T> : EditForm<T> { } // <-- ???

class AdvConcreteForm : AdvConcreteFormDesignable { }
class AdvConcreteFormDesignable : AdvEditForm<int> { }
```

How to make AdvEditForm designable?

**EDIT (for Alex Aza):**

It's not clear to me, what I should put into AdvEditForm.cs and AdvEditForm.Designer.cs exactly...

AdvEditForm.Designer.cs:

```
public partial class NonGenericAdvEditForm { }
```

AdvEditForm.cs:

```
public partial class NonGenericAdvEditForm : AdvEditForm<Object> { }
public class AdvEditForm<T> : EditForm<T>  { }
```

But I don't understand from which class I should inherit AdvConcreteForm:

```
class AdvConcreteForm : AdvConcreteFormDesignable { }
class AdvConcreteFormDesignable : ??????? { }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure I understand. Can you make a step back and explain why you need generic form <T> and how you are going to use it? What would help is to know what are possible T you expect and how would you like to instantiate the form (usage).

Comment: There is a generic edit form (EditForm<T>) with a grid and ribbon controls. It shows an entity (of type T, subclass of XPBaseObject) list and allows one to edit these entities, remove selected entites, reload them from data source and save changes. It supports in-place entity editing only. And now I need to extend EditForm<T> (let's call subclassed form AdvEditForm<T>). I want to add an EditEntityButton to ribbon control, which will show a popup editing form for each entity. Also I need an CreateEntityButton. And also I want to change some grid control properties.

Comment: I will subclass real editing forms (for concrete entitiy types) from both EditForm<T> and AdvEditForm<T>... And I will instantinate these non-generic subclasses. Hmm... but it would be interest to instantinate generic forms EditForm<MyBusinessObject>...

Answer (score 2):

You could add non-generic class just for `Design` purposes.

```
class NonGenericAdvEditForm : AdvEditForm<ConcreteType>
{
}
```

Designer needs concrete class, like `AdvEditForm<int>` or `AdvEditForm<MyType>`. It is not possible to instantiate `AdvEditForm<T>` without specifying what T is. The way to specify concrete T is to create a concrete non-generic class.

Comment: Thanks... but I don't understand from which class I should inherit AdvConcreteForm... (see **edit** in my question)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice solution for this problem http://madprops.org/blog/designing-generic-forms/

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i've found is:

```
// 1 Uncomment for design
//public partial class EntityListViewWithEditor<TEntity> : EntityListViewDesignable
// 2 Uncomment for compilation
public partial class EntityListViewWithEditor<TEntity> : EntityListView<TEntity>
    where TEntity : XPBaseObject
{ }

// 1 Uncomment for design
//public class EntityListViewDesignable : EntityListView<XPBaseObject> { }
```